# git credential suddenly fails

Tags: git, cygwin

I have suddenly started to get these errors when I try to pull or push

```
$ git pull

fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.

error: cannot spawn /usr/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass: No such file or directory
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Install or re-install `git-gui` as you seem to lack `/usr/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass`

```
$ cygcheck -p usr/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass
Found 3 matches for usr/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass
git-gui-2.15.1-1 - git-gui: Graphical interface for Git version control system
git-gui-2.16.1-1 - git-gui: Graphical interface for Git version control system
git-gui-2.16.2-1 - git-gui: Graphical interface for Git version control system
```

Comment: I ran cygwin installation again and chose to explicitly re-install git and git-gui, so problem is fixed. Will never find out how git-gui suddenly vanished.